# How do I initialize the content of Flutter package html_editor_enhanced?

Tags: flutter

I have made a web page for html editing making use of the latest version of Flutter html_editor_enhanced.  I successfully saved the html content to the backend mysql, the problem I am facing is I don't know how to put the content as initial value for the html editor.

```
class _EditColumnState extends State<EditColumn> {
  final HtmlEditorController controller = HtmlEditorController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    GetRecordDetail();
  }

  Future<void> GetRecordDetail() async {
    var url = setURL('/cms/news_details', {'id': widget.ID.toString()});  //my own procedure to set URL
    final response = await http.get(url, headers: globals.httpHeaders);
    var raw = convert.jsonDecode(response.body)[0];
    controller.setText(raw['content']);
    controller.reloadWeb();
     setState(() {

     });
  }
```

Please help.

Comment: HtmlEditor onInit(){controller.setText(DisplayContent)

Comment: please add this comment as a well formatted answer, because not all people look at the comments and might just miss it!

Answer (score 0):

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
          controller.setText(raw['content']);
        });
      });
```

wrap the setText method in delayed. this will work.